# Modifying the date

Tags: php, date

I have this problem in how can i modify the date.

**First, I need to input two dates(date start and date end) in createsched.php**

```
    <form name="createsched" id="createsched" method="post" action="addsched1.php">
   <div id= "sched" class="createsched">Date Start&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="datestart" name="datestart" placeholder="Start date"/><br></br>
    Date End&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="dateend" name="dateend" placeholder="End date"/><br></br>
    <input type="submit" id="createsched" name="createsched" value="Create Sched" class="buttonarea"/></div>
    </form>
```

when the createsched button is pressed it will go to another page name addsched1.php

**In addsched1.php i want to output the day and date, so i did this**

```
        $datestart=stripslashes($datestart);
        $dateend=stripslashes($dateend);

        $datestart=mysql_real_escape_string($datestart);
        $dateend=mysql_real_escape_string($dateend);


        $datestart= strtotime($datestart);
        $dateend= strtotime($dateend);

        $datestart= date('l-m/d/y',$datestart);
        $dateend= date('l-m/d/y',$dateend);
```

**I tried to output the $datestart and $dateend. It outputs correct value**

```
        $date=new DateTime($datestart);
        $date=date_modify($date, '+1 day');

       echo $date;
       ?>
```

**ERROR**

```
     Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (Monday-07/28/14) at position 9 (/): Unexpected character'in C:\xampp\htdocs\addsched1.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\addsched1.php(18):DateTime->__construct('Monday-07/28/14') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\addsched1.php on line 18
```

what i am doing wrong in this code? 
thanks :D

Comment: It's not the cause of the problem, but you shouldn't escape the variable before calling `strtotime()`. That's only needed when inserting the value into a SQL query.

Comment: The problem is that `strtotime()` doesn't understand the date format `Monday-07/28/14`.

Comment: Take a look on [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), those are the accepted formats in the `DateTime` constructor

Comment: Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) if you want to use a format that isn't recognized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects the time to be in a specific format. If your string does not meet any standard time format, it can't be transformed into a date. A complete list of valid formats can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

You can remove the following lines as they serve no purpose:

```
$datestart=stripslashes($datestart);
$dateend=stripslashes($dateend);

$datestart=mysql_real_escape_string($datestart);
$dateend=mysql_real_escape_string($dateend);
```

A html5 date input field should not return such a strange string, but to transform the string into something workable, you can use the following code:

```
$strange = "Monday-07/28/14";
$strange = explode( "-", $strange );
$strange = explode( "/", $strange[1] );
$unixtime = mktime( 0,0,0, $strange[0], $strange[1], $strange[2] );
echo date( "d-m-Y", $unixtime );
```

Comment: I tried to remove `striplashes and mysql_real_escape_string` the error still the same . thanks

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice the string that was passed to strtotime was in the question. I am unsure how you can even get that string from a html5 date element. They either render as an actual date picker and return yyyy-mm-dd or render as a regular input-field and there would be no reason to enter the date as DayName-dd/mm/yy

Comment: yes, i got the html5 date element in a format mm/dd/yyyy and when i output the $datestart and $dateend in a format l-m/d/y. The code can also determine the day(Monday - Sunday) of the $datestart and $dateend.

Comment: Why don't you put that mm/dd/yyyy into php's date magic, and pull everything, include the day of the week, from there? I have adjusted my answer to get the correct date object from the strange string, but it would be wise to construct it from the date string you get from the html5 field. Make sure to validate that it is in that format. Please note that the only good way to store dates is by storing the unix timestamp.